# Offsetting columns in bootstrap doesn't work for second row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a weather app. I have two rows which describe the current local weather conditions, and since I'm using bootstrap's grid system, I need to use `offset`s to (somewhat) center the columns on the page.

I have two `row`s, with `ID`s as `row-1` and `row-2`. The row `row-1` works fine when I apply an `offset` to the `div` inside it, but the same thing doesn't work for `row-2`.

Here's the relevant bit -

```
    <div class="row" id="row-1">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-4" id="picture"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row" id="row-2">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-4" id="area"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" id="conditions"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" id="wind-speed"></div>

    </div>
```

And here's the Pen on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nyxx/full/VepOqj/).

The problem appears to be that `col-xs-offset-4` does not seem to be applied on the first div inside `row-2`, ie - `<div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-4" id="area"></div>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following code you have:

```
#row-2 div {
    background-color: #DFDEDD;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and

```
#area {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

They override the

```
.col-xs-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
}
```

that is specified by bootstrap.

Comment: I see. I was trying to create a separation(a margin of sorts) between each of the 3 `div`s inside `row-2` with `margin:10px;`, otherwise all the `div`s appeared contiguous. Any idea how I can do that without messing up bootstrap's `margin-left`?

Comment: Yeah, just use `margin-right:20px` in `#row-2 div` and remove the `#area` code - which i am not sure why it exists -, it will not override bootstrap's `margin-left` and you will have the same spacing between the elements like before.